# Struggling to clip raster to vector in IDRISI. Windows do not overlap

Tags: raster, vector, terrset

I am trying to clip my raster to my vector in IDRISI. When I try to convert the vector to raster using my blank, it says vector and raster windows do not overlap. How do I fix this. I know I should use reformat - window, but I don't know what min and max x and y values I should use.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Are you sure the two datasets are in the same projection